# What insect is this? (India)

Tags: entomology, species-identification, taxonomy

Can anyone tell me what kind of insect (if it is one) is this...!! Or is it the pupa of some insect?

[image]

Well I don't think that the whole big thing is the insect itself, it appears to be just a kind of protection or shelter which moves along with the tiny little thing that keeps on popping out and going it so as to move.

Location:  India

Comment: I think it is worth adding a few pieces of information, to aid identification: the case is grey, without grains on its surface and tufts of hairy projections present on each end of the case.

Comment: Might be useful : if the same [Tineinae](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNZUDqZPMRY)

Comment: Related: [Identifying a creature that appears to be a worm wrapped in a cocoon](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/28479), [What is this black and white worm in a white case?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61326/),  [Help in identifying an unknown arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/55519/), [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/15845), [Identify this smooth-cocoon worm from Southern India](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/47912), [Small worm living in some kind of cocoon...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1808)...

Comment: Related:  [What is this animal that hides in dustlike structure?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43723), [What in the world is this critter?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9465), [What is this hard shelled insect in my house?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88209), [What is this insect found commonly in coastal India?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/48197), [Insect identification - pantry moth vs clothes moth](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73656)

Answer (score 19):

This is mostly a guess and loose suggestion, since the picture is not very clear (would need to see the larvae in more detail). However, [Bagworm moths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth) (Psychidae), [Case moths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-bearer) (Coleophoridae) and [Caddisfly larvae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caddisfly) (Trichoptera, almost exclusively aquatic) all build similar cases. They construct their cases out if silk and often include debris, pebbles and other materials. I wouldn't be surprised if the larvae in your picture belongs to one of the first two taxa. Bagworm moths and Caddisflies generally include lots of external materials in their larval cases, which could point to Case moths for your specimen (which seems to have a weaker case mostly made of silk).

Here are two pictures of first a UK Case moth larvae ([*Coleophora deauratella*](http://ukmoths.org.uk/showzoom.php?id=5907)) followed by a Bagworm moth ([*Dahlica triquetrella*](http://xenogere.com/2010/04/28/rainy-day-on-the-patio/)), just as comparisons. If you do google image searches of "group name + larvae" you will see many examples of what they can look like.
[image]
[image]

And just as a cool example - the larvae often use random material lying around to build their cases, which can give the following result, if caddisfly larvae are bred in a tank containing pieces if gold and pearls. For further information see [this link](http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2013/02/french-artist-gives-caddisfly-larvae-gold-jewels-to-build-their-protective-cases.html).

[image]

Comment: I'll just comment that caddisfly larvae are aquatic and will typically only be found in clean streams, ponds, or lakes. The two moth families you mention are much more likely based on the terrestrial location of the OP's insect. I wouldn't remove your info about the caddisflies as it can be useful/interesting to others coming across this question, but the aquatic/terrestrial differences in these insects' ecologies definitively rules out caddisflies.

Comment: @theforestecologist I agree, which is also why I mention in the answer that Trichoptera are almost exclusively aquatic.

Comment: @fileunderwater Oops I missed that. Well just giving further acknowledgment to that fact then :).

Answer (score -2):

It's a household casebearer, a kind of moth larva in the family Tineidae that builds this case around itself.

@fileunderwater is **wrong**

Comment: Can you substantiate your answer as why you thing so, ideally with citation and picture reference? Household casebearer as I'm aware of have dirt or grain covered case, when not covered in dirt, they are close to white and not grey. This species is not only grey but also has a smooth surface = no grains.

Comment: Could be, and, as I said in my answer, the ones I mention are loose suggestions, based on the rather poor picture. Could you maybe specify what makes you so sure that it is a Tineidae?