# What is this organism?

Tags: species-identification

[image: organism]
[Link to GIF on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNFEQ.jpg)

What is this flat organism? It is around 1 cm long. I find them in places which aren't cleaned often. Location is India. Are they harmful or poisonous?

Edit: I've found that this is a duplicate question of [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/15845/41722).