# What insect in shell is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arthropod

Location: INDIA(Tropical Monsoon)
I found an insect (approx 7mm) (marked with red in image) in my bedroom hanging from the roof.

1. It can spin some kind of thread, since it was hanging at the first place
2. It has a shell like structure (marked with blue in image), and it stays inside the shell.

I forced it out of its shell. Its image is given below. I also recorded [a video](https://s7.gifyu.com/images/ezgif-1-0e15d93580.gif) of its behaviours.

[image: Insect and its shell]

Comment: Please consider converting your video (or parts of it) to GIFs and adding them directly to this post. Sites like ezgif.com have simple tools for converting videos to gifs, trimming length, and optimizing file size. Including this info here would be beneficial. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15845/what-insect-is-this-india)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I'm almost certain it's a bagworm, or a moth larva in the Psychidae family. I'm no lepidopterist, I can't confidently narrow it down to genus or species level from there.

Comment: You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. Please also provide a [citation/source](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for images. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.