# What is this insect found commonly in coastal India?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I have lived in two cities on the western coast of India and I have seen quite a few of these insects(?) in both places.

[image: Weird insect]

It basically has an outer cocoon of sorts, which looks a lot like dirty lint. The actual insect is a small wormlike creature at the top of the cocoon. It almost always tries to keep climbing up walls and when it dies, it remains stuck to the wall from its topmost point. The overall length of it, including the linty cocoon is about half a centimeter.

Can someone tell me what these are and if I need to actively avoid them or prevent their appearance in my closet?

Comment: Also http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/47912/identify-this-cocoon-worm#comment83618_47912 ... and also http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/small-worm-living-in-some-kind-of-cocoon-what-are-these-animals

Comment: Related: [Identifying a creature that appears to be a worm wrapped in a cocoon](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/28479), [What is this black and white worm in a white case?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61326/),  [Help in identifying an unknown arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/55519/), [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/15845), [Identify this smooth-cocoon worm from Southern India](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/47912), [Small worm living in some kind of cocoon...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1808)...

Comment: Related:  [What is this animal that hides in dustlike structure?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43723), [What in the world is this critter?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9465), [What is this hard shelled insect in my house?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88209), [What is this insect found commonly in coastal India?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/48197), [Insect identification - pantry moth vs clothes moth](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73656)