# Help in identifying an unknown arthropod

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm not even sure it's an insect:  the best I can do is identify it as an arthropod.  I captured this slow-moving organism and after a period of observation under high magnification, I concluded that it appears to construct a "shell" from miscellaneous particles or debris.  With a scalpel, I carefully cut this outer casing open to observe the organism, and the pictures show what I found.  It seems to have six legs, like an insect, but is oddly worm-like and wingless.  Total length is approximately 1 cm.  I do not believe that this is a juvenile/larval/instar form.  I've seen several of these where I live, and they always look like this (with maybe a +/- 20% size variation).

---

Edit:  This specimen was found in San Diego County, California, United States.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Closely related question/answer: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15845/what-insect-is-this/15856#15856

Comment: We have a lot of these in our house.

Comment: We have a ton of these in our garage! (Los Angeles) Thanks so much for asking, I've always been curious about them.

Comment: These case building moths have shown up a few times on this site. Hands down, though, these are the best pictures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the larva of **household casebearer** moth (a Lepidoptera), named after the larval stage. It is scientifically called *Phereoeca uterella*.

It is found through out South and North America.

[image]

[image]

> The larva constructs a protective case from silk and camouflages it with other materials such as soil, sand and insect droppings.

**References:**

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phereoeca_uterella)
- [bugguide](http://bugguide.net/node/view/954610)

---

**Further reading:** Household Casebearer, Phereoeca uterella by
Juan A. Villanueva-Jimenez and Thomas R. Fasulo

Comment: so does cutting off it's shell (like the OP did) harm it? Or can it just grow another shell?

Comment: @user17915 There is no scientific work on the impact of removal of the larva from its case but I think it does affect the larva if done so because there must be a real significance behind spending a lot of energy synthesising the threads of the case which begins even before the larva hatches out.