# What moth is this and how do we get rid of them?

Tags: species-identification, lepidoptera, pest-control

[image] 
This bugs are everywhere in my house and we've tried so many home remedies, but they won't leave. Can anyone help us!?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I suggest you to take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site and earn your first badge. Also, it is useful to include your geographical location when looking for a species identification.

Comment: Also check any cat or dog dry food if you have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an Indian meal moth *Plodia interpunctella*. Family Pyralidae. They are very common household pests. https://www.doyourownpestcontrol.com/indian_meal_moth.htm
They breed in grains or cereals. You need to look through your pantry, and find out what they have been breeding in. Seal up your grains and cereals in plastic, or put them all in the fridge.

Comment: They are also known in some areas as _pantry moths_, due to their association with that location, i.e. infestation. Note that plastic bags will not keep them out as both the adult moths and the grubs can chew though thin plastic. Infested plastic bags will have a multitude of silk threads, small uneaten food particles, and grub cases in it. The plastic containers need to have thick solid walls with an airtight lid.

Comment: Yes, you need to go through the items in your pantry, probably you will find some infested bags/boxes. Discarding them will help in getting rid of them.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a common [flour moth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianmeal_moth) or a similar pyralid species. It has probably laid eggs in some cereal-derived products (pasta, cous cous, but also rice, oatmeal and the like) of your kitchen. First of all, check carefully your pantry for infested food and throw it away. Then (from the above Wikipedia link):

> None of the stages of the organism (eggs, larvae, adults) are very temperature tolerant and all can be killed by a week of freezing or by brief heating in a microwave or conventional oven when such treatment is practical. Scrubbing infested areas with a mixture of soap and water or vinegar is also effective. [...] Nontoxic traps are also available to monitor outbreaks. One type of trap is a triangular box with a pheromone lure and sticky walls inside. These traps are generally known as pheromone traps. In this case, male moths are attracted inside by the female pheromone (the lure) and then get stuck against the sticky walls inside the box.

From personal experience, it can be sufficient to check the pantry and seal all the cereal-derived food into plastic bags.

Comment: It's possible you had a different species to the one I encountered. Mine were capable of chewing through plastic bags and infesting them. See my comment on Karl Kjer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but for the possible sake of later readers, with respect to mentioning plastic bags - at least some, if not all of the moth species commonly known to infest households do have a reputation for being able to bite through thin plastic bags, both the larvae and the adult moths.

Where that's the case, or can be suspected anyway, recommendations I have found are to use hard plastic containers with a tightly (and forcefully) closing lid for endangered food etc.

*Quick sourcing (I did have sufficient original reputable sources when I wrote this answer passing by, the memory of them just eluded me)*:

[This](https://www.who.com.au/pantry-moths-how-to-get-rid-of) internet article states, though rather informally,

> the larvae ... can bite through plastic and cardboard, [or] work their way through a screw lid jar if it’s not tightly closed.

[This official page of this U.S. National Pest Information center*](http://npic.orst.edu/pest/pantrymoth.html) states explicitly (first paragraph there as of time viewed)

> Larvae can chew through plastic bags and thin cardboard, so even unopened packages may become infested.

[NPIC](http://npic.orst.edu/about.html) is, from the page footer here and on other pages, *a cooperative agreement between Oregon State University and the U.S. Environmental Protection Agency*.

*NOTE: Sourcing to continue as required...*

Comment: Sources for this are pretty common across the web so no special citations here in this case *(unless it gets requested and I find the time)*

Comment: Please *always* provide citations when posting answers on this site. Otherwise, your post is likely to be downvoted or removed. Thanks!

Comment: oops - got called out within 2 minutes for not adding explicit sources and citations. Received a downvote along with a message with that. Well, received. But please, @theforestecologist and everybody, just give me some time for that, will you?

Comment: BTW, for the hygiene of the knowledgebase - which I accept - I might temporarily retract my answer but I'm uncertain about whether that would remove it irrecoverably. Would that be a way to go, @theforestecologist? Thanks again for the heads-up. - **Background information**: I am really right now doing my due prior research for another question that I believe is not in the system at all but exactly to make sure it really is distinct I am reading all the QAs that the system thinks they might be. That's how I came across this question in the first place.

Comment: This post was written with no other intention than to be helpful. Please.

Comment: **As for the "screw lid" part**, I haven't consciously read that anywhere else but here the critical factor seems to be "if it's not tightly closed". Big deal.

Comment: @theforestecologist does this qualify for this answer to be reset to +- 0 votes?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Unfortunately, I think you've answered a question different from that originally posed. I would vote this up if the question was something like "Can pantry moths really chew through plastic bags?". As it stands you've made a detailed comment on a side issue rather than an answer to the OPs question. Since you've put in so much work maybe you can find a question that this does answer? Thanks! 

Comment: thanks @tyersome, will try. As stated in my other comments, I was just dropping by doing adjacent research and thought I'd add a missing bit to be helpful to any latecoming readers **because of other comments** and I could not do that simply in a comment bc rep, however much I would have loved to. **I very much appreciate your analysis and suggestion** (and your not adding another downvote :-)), just if I could be allowed a little time for that?

Comment: On moving this answer: Have now checked using the site search for "Can pantry moths really chew through plastic bags?", some variations of that, and "moth chew plastic" (all yield zero), then "moth eat plastic" yielded exactly [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73656/60395). **Now I guess this would really be an edge case** as [the accepted and high-rep only answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/73685/60395) does briefly mention the essence of this answer, giving the same reputable source and link on the point. Now to look what part of the help pages would cover what to do here?

Comment: To me that question still doesn't really fit your answer. I think you might want to post a question about how to use your answer on [meta] — the moderators will often answer questions there. One possibility is for you to post a question and then answer it yourself, but I'm not completely sure how well that would be received ... ———— As for downvotes, to the extent possible it is best not to take them personally. Some users downvote ⋯ enthusiastically ⋯ without giving useful feedback, but many new users ignore feedback or respond angrily to comments. Stick around and you'll also see upvotes! 

Comment: Thanks again tylersome (can't 'at' two users) - I'll take your advice to ask about that on Biology Meta, even more so as the *intersecting* [answer I mentioned](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/73685/60395) was @theforestecologist's and they are a mod. I might first complete my research on the other question I'm preparing though as it might help with explaining what I was doing in the first place (was doing my due prior research on that question by which I came across this question and noticed that it might help late readers if I added a missing bit, which could have been a comment if ...)

Comment: Thanks again @tylersome - I'll take your advice and ask on Biology Meta. Please note another comment I just added above this one (to ping theforestecologist for the reason given there, system is telling me I can't 'at' two users in one comment)

Comment: @somebody_other thanks for updating with some citations and support. I've removed the post notice. We get many unsupported posts here, so quickly responding with post notices is paramount for trying to get users to take that aspect of our site's expectations seriously. (see our help page and take our [tour]). This is an especially big problem with a topic like species ID, which is typically rampant with inaccuracies across the internet. Nothing personal. Just nipping the problem in the bud to cut down dealing with it later. Thanks Shahin for the update

Comment: Regarding rep limitations: these are in place partially to force you to get involved in our site so that you learn the ins and outs. You can only earn rep through asking, answering, or editing. Each of these are "graded" by the community here through voting. In other words, you only earn rep if the community approves. You earn more priveleges the more rep ("trust") you earn. Just a few upvotes or a handful of edits enables you to comment. So please stick around, get to know how things work a bit more, edit some posts, answer more questions, and you'll be on your way in no time!

Comment: @tyersome, apologies for consistently mistyping your username unawares so I guess you didnt get my ping. In case you're interested, see above. Thanks a lot for your helpful comments.

Comment: @theforestecologist might I get your opinion as a mod and the author of [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/73685/60395): I 'd un-offtopic my answer as tyersome suggested by making it a separate question (that I could link to, too). I worry whether the second-last line of your above answer would make a "sort of" duplicate of it, though. AFAIS there's no "real" duplicate yet. tyersome suggested I should ask about this on Biology Meta (a bit high?) - now as it concerns your answer and you are a mod yourself, what do you say I should do? And thanks a lot for the explaining & encouraging!