# What is this black and white worm in a white case?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The case is very small and it's an off white color.

The thing living inside can come out of either end. It's a black and white looking worm. It will poke its head out and move everywhere!

[image]

They are all over my back porch and some are even coming in my house!

Comment: Could you link more (and clearer) pictures please?

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15845/what-insect-is-this-india/15856#15856

Comment: @arboviral I also thought it was a duplicate... however, the answerer in that question mentions several families, but not Tineidae.

Comment: Related [Question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/help-in-identifying-an-unknown-arthropod).

Comment: Related: [Identifying a creature that appears to be a worm wrapped in a cocoon](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/28479), [What is this black and white worm in a white case?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61326/),  [Help in identifying an unknown arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/55519/), [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/15845), [Identify this smooth-cocoon worm from Southern India](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/47912), [Small worm living in some kind of cocoon...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1808)...

Comment: Related:  [What is this animal that hides in dustlike structure?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43723), [What in the world is this critter?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9465), [What is this hard shelled insect in my house?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88209), [What is this insect found commonly in coastal India?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/48197), [Insect identification - pantry moth vs clothes moth](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73656)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying a creature that appears to be a worm wrapped in a cocoon](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28479/identifying-a-creature-that-appears-to-be-a-worm-wrapped-in-a-cocoon)

Answer (score 34):

This is just a larva of a moth from the Family [Tineidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tineidae), most probably [*Phereoeca uterella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phereoeca_uterella) (known as plaster bagworm or household casebearer), or [*Tinea pellionella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinea_pellionella) (known as case-bearing clothes moth).

As you can see, the larva of this moth...

> ... constructs a protective case from silk and camouflages it with other materials such as soil, sand and insect droppings. (from Wikipedia)

Here is a better picture of *Phereoeca uterella*, from the entomology deptartment of the [University of Florida](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/household_casebearer01.jpg):

[image]

Here is the imago (adult), for comparison:

[image]

Comment: @Lynn If this answer helped you, consider "Accepting" it (hit the check mark under the down-vote icon). Glad you got what you were looking for!