# What is this hard shelled insect in my house?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I moved to a new city in west India last year and I've since, on several occasions, seen this insect on walls and it's usually climbing using its head. It has a greyish long shell and moves in a very wobbly way. I've asked people in the locality if they know what that insect is, but no one has a clue. And my curiosity is piqued everytime I see it and I really want to know what it is. [image]

Here are two closeup images:
https://ibb.co/HNDLCMm
https://ibb.co/6JCMH7j

I have a video as well but I don't know how to share it here.

I was suggested that this question is a possible duplicate of: [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15845/what-insect-is-this-india)

The insect in my case is probably much smaller and has a plain grey shell (as opposed to building a shell from material lying around, which would most probably be different every time). I don't explicitly see any legs although there may be.

I want a definitive answer as to what moth it is or if it is one or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15845/what-insect-is-this-india)

Comment: I think if you want a better ID you need a much much better picture.

Comment: Your close-up images are not any better than the current one.

Comment: Related: [Identifying a creature that appears to be a worm wrapped in a cocoon](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/28479), [What is this black and white worm in a white case?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61326/),  [Help in identifying an unknown arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/55519/), [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/15845), [Identify this smooth-cocoon worm from Southern India](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/47912), [Small worm living in some kind of cocoon...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1808)...

Comment: Related:  [What is this animal that hides in dustlike structure?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43723), [What in the world is this critter?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9465), [What is this hard shelled insect in my house?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88209), [What is this insect found commonly in coastal India?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/48197), [Insect identification - pantry moth vs clothes moth](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73656)

Answer (score -1):

That's a plaster bagworm [ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phereoeca_uterella ] :)

Comment: Doubt if it's the same species. Probably a different one since it's always grey (but could be that the larvae are rising from same source and using the same material). It is a moth larva for sure though right?

Comment: For sure it's a moth larva because it's order is Lepidoptera.. and lepidopterans are either butterflies or moths.