# Species Identification : Worm like insect but broad at back

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Can anyone help me identify this insect

Location: Southern India

Size: About 2cm

It looks like a worm but has a broad back, it seems like (not very sure) it tucks it's thin head inside the broad shell like body to ward off.

Here is the picture,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please always include your location and the approximate size of your specimen

Comment: Related: [Identifying a creature that appears to be a worm wrapped in a cocoon](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/28479), [What is this black and white worm in a white case?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61326/),  [Help in identifying an unknown arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/55519/), [What insect is this? (India)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/15845), [Identify this smooth-cocoon worm from Southern India](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/47912), [Small worm living in some kind of cocoon...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1808)...

Comment: Related:  [What is this animal that hides in dustlike structure?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43723), [What in the world is this critter?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9465), [What is this hard shelled insect in my house?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88209), [What is this insect found commonly in coastal India?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/48197), [Insect identification - pantry moth vs clothes moth](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73656)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually looks like some sort of [caddisfly larvae](https://www.google.com/search?q=cadice%20fly%20larvae&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjqmY_P_qvoAhUU4oUKHbQzBdgQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=cadice%20fly%20larvae&gs_l=img.3...46203.54167..54984...0.0..0.89.955.12......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0j0i5i30j0i7i30.9NXIQcnWAXI&ei=CUF2XqrxIJTElwS055TADQ&bih=616&biw=1280&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711) in its case to me.

[image]
[image]

Are you sure that's it's 'body' & not a case?

Did you find it in water?

Or a Case Bearing Clothes Moth (Caddisfly are closely related to moths).

This one (a [clothes moth larvae](http://case%20bearing%20clothes%20moth%20larvae)) looks very similar to your image.

[image]

Comment: This is not a caddisfly. Caddisflies are only found in water. Also note the bulging shape of the case -- such non-hydrodynamic shape would be quite challenging for the caddisfly to stay in place. The OP's specimen does in fact look like a case-bearing moth 
(similar to the many linked posts I added in the comments above). In the future, please make sure that images and sources you use are reputable. Alamy stock photos are *VERY* often mislabeled and wrong, so using them as a form of evidence should be avoided or at least corroborated by better info. Also note that your link does not work.